# IOS/AppStore How to Submit New Release of Existing App For Review

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an approved iphone app in the App Store. The first build that was approved and is now in the store was version 1.0, build 10.

I successfully uploaded a new build. It appears under the Activity All Builds tab in My App Connect. However, App Store Status is blank and when I hover over the build # which happens to be 11, nothing happens and I can't figure out how to submit it for review.

This is what the activity tab looks like:

[image]

The new build is not visible in the App Store versions tab.

How do I submit it for review? Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the "App Store" tab instead of "Activity" tab. If you haven't already, click on the "+ Version or Platform" link and add the new iOS version. Then select that new version. Fill in all of the details. Then next to the Build section, click the circled + icon and select your build. Save the changes and submit for review.

Comment: Ok.  Looks like I have to re-enter a lot of the stuff that was in existing build....Is that right?

Comment: No, most of it should already be there. You need to fill in the version information. Everything else should appear from the original release. You have the option of updating the screenshots and app description if needed.